# numpy.empty creates array of shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am creating a new array using `empty` functionality in `numpy`. As input for shape, if I put `(a,) + (b,)` where `a` and `b` are integers, it creates an array of shape `(a,b)`. Why it's not creating an array of shape `(a+b,)`?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> empty_array = np.empty((a,) + (b,), dtype = np.float)
>>> print(empty_array.shape)
(5, 3)
>>> print(empty_array)
[[-2.68156159e+154 -2.68156159e+154  4.44659081e-323]
 [ 0.00000000e+000  2.12199579e-314  0.00000000e+000]
 [ 0.00000000e+000  0.00000000e+000  1.77229088e-310]
 [ 3.50977866e+064  0.00000000e+000  8.34402697e-309]
 [ 6.94946729e-310  2.54639495e-313  0.00000000e+000]]
```

Comment: `(a,) + (b,) = (a,b)`

Comment: why not `(a,) + (,b) = (a,b)`?

Comment: `+` operator for tuples, (this is a tuple `(3,)`), does concatenation, not arithmetic addition

Comment: A basic Python point - function arguments are evaluated before being passed in.  So the issue here isn't the behavior of `np.empty`.